# Building a library in an Android Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have just gotten a new computer and I'm in the process of setting up Eclipse to carry on working with my Java and Android projects.

My workspace was saved on Dropbox, but to make things easier I started a new workspace and imported my Android project, a second Android project that I'm using as a library and the `appcompat_v7` and `google-play-services_lib`.

I am now getting an error The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library referring to the second project I'm using as a library. When I check the bin folder of the project there are no JAR file so I get why I'm getting this error.

So my question is how do I create the jar file in the bin folder of my project. I have the project ticked as "isLibrary" in the `properties>android` and in the first project I have the second project listed in the reference section of `properties>andriod`.

Comment: Android support for eclipse has been abandoned. Google recommends to use Android Studio to compile Android projects. You can still use eclipse, I just want to let you know that it is not recommended for app development.

Comment: that means the library project failed to be build, once it got built the jar file will be generated, try to clean and rebuild or check if all it's dependencies are correct and exist... ALSO make sure checkbox `is Library` is selected for that library project